# How to display a Windows 8 metro style tile within an app?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

Windows 8 metro style app tiles are created based on pre-defined xml templates (found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh761491.aspx)).

Is there any way to hook up to Windows' rendering of the tile to allow a tile preview within an app?

In my app I would like to offer the user a subset of the tile templates listed in the above link and let the user customize the tile content. A live preview of the customized tile rendered within my app would greatly improve the user experience.

Answer (score 4):

you should look into [HubTile](http://www.telerik.com/products/windows-8/controls/hubtile.aspx).

I don't know any free control's right now, but Telerik and Syncfusion have HubTile control

Answer (score 0):

You can't get access to real Windows tile rendering, but you can simulate it since all templates are known. It is very unlikely that Microsoft would change the way tiles are rendered and even if they do you should be able to issue app update to keep up with Microsoft.