# How do I programmatically navigate to the start screen from within a Windows 8 javascript app?

Tags: windows-8, winjs

I am developing an app that allows the user to make certain changes to tiles on the Windows 8 start screen. When a change has been made within the app, the user will be shown a "View my changes" button. Clicking the button should bring the user back to the start screen.

I have looked into different ways of closing/suspending the app programmatically (and thus taking the user to the start screen), but I have not found a way to achieve this using WinJS. Throwing an exception closes the app, but this seems like a very dirty workaround. Any suggestions?

Comment: I think they deliberately excluded that functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are creating secondary tiles and want to show the users what they look like? @mydogisbox is right in that this kind of functionality has probably been deliberatly excluded.

I'd recommend to just do an in-app 'view changes' of whatever changes to secondary tiles the user might have made. In general, I'd argue that this would be a better user experience because you will keep the user engaged within your application and not be essentially kicking them out of the experience.

Comment: Thanks, your assumption is correct. I will be looking into in-app tile previews in the next version, but supporting various kind of tiles in wide and narrow state is quite a lot of work, especially as it seems I can't hook on to Windows' own tile rendering mechanisms (see [this stack overflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13330364/how-to-display-a-windows-8-metro-style-tile-within-an-app))